# Objective c save to my plist

Tags: objective-c, plist, core-location

I have the plist file under the resources folder which is name is logical-app.plist
In ios8 if you want Gps will work then NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription keys should be added into the Info.plist

I want to add NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription keys in code in my appdelegate class.

Im trying to add the following code for solving this issue:

```
//write
filePath = @"/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist";
plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

[plistDict setValue:@"1.1.1" forKey:@"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription"];
[plistDict writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES];
//endwrite

//read plist
filePath = @"/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist";
plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];


value = [plistDict objectForKey:@"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription"];
```

im trying to get 
 filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ClickMobileCDV-Info" ofType:@"plist"];
and it is nil too....

But with no success.... when i read it from the plist it was nil...

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: You should locate the plist file in your app's `Documents` directory.

Comment: ... and you don't need to code to add values to it.

Answer (score 1):

You've completely got the wrong end of the stick.  In order to add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`, you edit the app's plist file within Xcode and it's included in the app bundle.

There is no code needed to read/write system `.plist` files at runtime (the writing of which would fail anyway, due to permission errors).